# The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'(with asynchronous function)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am working on this app and keep getting this error. No solutions have worked so far.

```
_initialize() async{

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool loggedIn = prefs.getBool(LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
if(!loggedIn){
  _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
}else{
  await auth.currentUser.then((User currentUser) async{
    _user = currentUser;
    _status = Status.Authenticated;
    _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(currentUser.uid);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the property `currentUser` is not a `Future`, it gives you the value immediately, so you can't wait for it and you don't even have to.

So the else block should be:

```
else {
    _user = auth.currentUser;
    _status = Status.Authenticated;
    _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(auth.currentUser.uid);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**NEVER** ever use a .then

With a high probability, from my experience, if you are using a `future.then` in your code, you are doing something wrong.

After this premise:

You probably don't understand what you are doing, here some comments and a proper formatting for you to understand better.

```dart
//It is a good practice to always mark the return type 
void _initialize() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool loggedIn = prefs.getBool(LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
    if(!loggedIn){
        _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    }else{
        //You are awaiting the future currentUser. But in fact, it isn't a future at all, as you can read [here][1]
        await auth.currentUser.then((User currentUser) async{
            _user = currentUser;
            _status = Status.Authenticated;
            _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(currentUser.uid);
        });
    }
}
```

The code you should use should be something like this:

```dart
//It is a good practice to always mark the return type 
void _initialize() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool loggedIn = prefs.getBool(LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
    if(!loggedIn){
        _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    }else{
        _user = auth.currentUser;
        _status = Status.Authenticated;
        _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(auth.currentUser.uid);
    }
}
```

1: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/

Comment: The use of `await` is equivalent to `.then()`, so why you are strongly warning from using `.then()`? Can you warn from using `await` too?

Comment: This can give you some idea. https://jelenaaa.medium.com/when-to-use-async-await-then-and-future-in-dart-5e00e64ab9b1 As I said, if you're not sure what to use, use await. In my experience (2 and a half years of programming in dart) I've never needed a .then

Comment: I have read the article and found nothing new, they both are the same and could achieve the same logic, the only difference is the arrangement of code while using each one.

Comment: .then makes the code go by and executes in the meanwhile, in a simplified way. if you use .then, you will have some problems with late variables. 90% of the time, you will have to use await. Please be sure to know what you're talking about and only then talk about it

Comment: Behave ❤️ I know exactly what I'm talking about 